# Loading UIView in a viewController when taped on the action button

Tags: uiview

In view controller i took the object view & placed 2 textfield & 2 uibutton through storyboard.I just want to add same view when user tap on the UIbutton without loosing the data in the text filed of the first view.

How i can access the data of all the view.

array

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `IBOutlets` by control-dragging from views in the storyboard to your viewcontroller's `@interface` section. Then you can access views' data using them.

If you want to perform some action when user taps a button you need to create an `IBAction` by control-dragging from the button in the storyboard to the `@implementation` section in your viewcontroller's code. Then you can add another view programmatically in the method created.